# component render one time when click tab on drawerNavigator in react native

Tags: react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer, react-native-navigation

I'm new on react native getting issue on calling component. Whenever click on drawer navigator tab first time component render and API called But when back to the home page and again call that component API not called. I want to recall that function.

Here is my drawer navigator code :

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="home" size={20} color="#0f1f7b" />
        )
    },
  },
  PreviousInspection: {
    screen: PreviousInspection,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Previous Inspection',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="file" size={20} color="#0f1f7b" />
        )
    },
  },
  Logout: {
    screen: Logout,
    navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Logout',
        drawerIcon: () => (
          <Icon name="sign-out" size={20} color="#0f1f7b" />
          )
    },
  }
},
{
  drawerBackgroundColor: "#fff",
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#000',
    inactiveTintColor: '#000',
    activeBackgroundColor: '#bfc7f3',
    itemStyle: {
      fontSize: 12,
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-navigation has a withNavigationFocus HOC which provides an isFocused prop to your component. You can use that to determine when a certain screen has become visible.

```js
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';

class YourScreen extends React.Component {

  render() {
     ...
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.isFocused && !prevProps.isFocused) {
      // Screen has now come into focus, call your method here 
    }
  }

}

export default withNavigationFocus(YourScreen)
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks buddy